# Upgrading go version to 1.11 in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade go version to `1.11` in ubuntu 16.04.

I try the following tutorial but it only upgrade user go version to `1.11`.

when i call `sudo go version` it still return go `1.6.2`.

How can i update the global go package to `1.11` instead?

Tutorial source: [Click here](https://medium.com/@RidhamTarpara/install-go-1-11-on-ubuntu-18-04-16-04-lts-8c098c503c5f)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the golang github wiki -

> If you're using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 18.04 LTS or 18.10, then you can use
>   the longsleep/golang-backports PPA and install Go 1.11. Note that
>   golang-go installs latest Go as default Go. If you do not want that,
>   install golang-1.11 instead and use the binaries from
>   /usr/lib/go-1.11/bin.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:longsleep/golang-backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install golang-go
```

Comment: how can i uninstall the installation of go in the previous tutorial for user then? The previous installation extract package downloaded and move to `/usr/local`

Comment: @eulercode - if you extracted the files and then moved as root wtih `sudo cp ...` or `sudo mv ...` then simply `sudo rm` them.  if they were installed via a `sudo make install` or similar, then perhaps there is a `make uninstall` available (rare, but i've seen and used them). can't really say for certain without knowing which tutorial you followed.  but basically, you have to reverse the steps, including any changes done via scripts.